# Android Handling Activity History with group of Activities

Tags: android, android-activity, navigation

Forgive me if there is an obvious answer to this. It wasn't that I didn't look, but rather I'm not even sure where to start.

Basically I have a button that is clicked which will take the user to a specific activity. I actually have a series of activities, all of which are related and navigate back and forth to to one another sequentially. My question is if the user hits the button that I mentioned, I want to take them back to the particular activity they were working on before they moved away from the set of activities. I just need some information on where o start here. Thanks.

Comment: Can you describe the flow of the task?  Can you add a hypothetical situation?

Comment: Let's say we start out with an activity that has 3 buttons, each takes you to a "parent" activity. One takes you to a listview, another to an activity that displays links, and finally (the one I am concerned with) the last button takes you to the "beginning" activity that is one of a series of sibling activities. I am looking for info to set up this type of navigation. I should also note that when you decide to leave the sibling activities, and essentially navigate back up to the main activity, I want to save all the information put into the sibling activities for the user to come back to.

Comment: Stick with the first question.  Leave persistence for when you finalize the App.  So with these 3 buttons, what is the error.  You said the last button takes you to the beginning activity, the launch activity?  If the current activity, the one with the buttons, was started from the launch activity then do not call `startActivity`, you'll need call `finish()`.  It will close your activity, call `onDestroy` and bring whatever previous activity in the stack to the front.